# Show that $\int \limits_{0}^{\pi} f(\sin x) \cos x dx=0$ for any $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Show that $\int \limits_{0}^{\pi} f(\sin x) \cos x \, dx =0$ for any function $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Hint: change of variable $u=\sin x$.

Comment: Is this intuitively true to anyone?

Comment: This would be a nice calculus exam question, with some disguise e.g. $\int_0^{\pi} (\sin x)^{\log(1+\sin x)}\cos x\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: @Did ... take care with substitutions that are not one-to-one.

Comment: I would guess the down votes are because OP doesn't explain his/her thoughts, and also because the post reads as a command instead of a request for help. But if you down vote and don't explain why, how will that help OP change behavior?

Comment: @GEdgar: Fortunately, there is no need to invert the substitution!

Comment: @GitGud After a few seconds thought, yes, sort of. Each value that is taken by $\sin(x)$ is taken twice, but with negative values for $\cos(x)$. So the function takes its positive values and the countering negative values with equal measure.

Comment: @alex.jordan Nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

First, we split up the integral into $\int_0^{\pi/2}{f(\sin x)\cos x dx}+\int_{\pi/2}^\pi{f(\sin x) \cos x dx}$, and then notice that by letting $\pi-y=x$, we have $$\int_{\pi/2}^\pi{f(\sin x)\cos x dx}=\int_{\pi/2}^{0}{-f(\sin (\pi-y)) \cos (\pi-y)dy}=-\int_0^{\pi/2}{f(\sin y)\cos y dy}.$$  Thus, we find that $$\int_0^\pi{f(\sin x)\cos x dx}=\int_0^{\pi/2}{f(\sin x)\cos x dx}-\int_0^{\pi/2}{f(\sin x)\cos x dx}=0$$

Comment: Up voted for originality, but I prefer Did's solution.

Comment: Figured I should make some kind of positive contribution after making dumb mistakes.

Comment: I prefer this solution since the symmetries of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are well known and immediatly imply this result.

Comment: I actually prefer this solution as well, the u-substitution is certainly easier, but the result seems strange (how can one integral over a non-zero domain transform to an integral from $0$ to $0$--it does, but I think it warrants a double take).

Comment: @Jared: It's no more weird than tracing out a closed curve; and the sine function on $[0, \pi]$ _is_ a closed curve in $\mathbf{R}$. :)

Answer (score 12):

Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, there exists $F$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f=F'$, then

$$\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)\cos x\ dx=\int_0^\pi(F(\sin x))'\ dx=[F(\sin x)]_0^\pi=F(0)-F(0)=0$$

Comment: Or even more briefly: By Did's substitution and change of variables, $$\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)\cos x\, dx = \int_0^0 f(u)\, du = 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $y=x-\frac {\pi}2$ and you will find that you are integrating an odd function with symmetric limits, which is trivially zero.